# SlideToggle doesn't work after ajax refreshed the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So now I have set up the slideToggle function, which is working well. But after I filtered the results, the slide doesn't work anymore. On this page you can see it: https://staging.therapeutischefrauenmassage.de/therapeutinnen/

After you filtered the results with a radio button click, the slides won't slide at all. What is the issue? The code would be useless because the ajax loads the file, which was included before and worked...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reattach the event listeners (like on(click,...), etc) once the ajax loads that section.  Since they are new to the DOM they will not have those listeners attached to them.

You could add a step at the end of the ajax load which detaches and reattaches the pertinent listeners.

---

Follow-up:

Here's your current code:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('h3').next('.slidetoggle').slideToggle();
});
```

Do this to clear any remaining linked event handlers (since we will add them back in just a moment):

```
$('.show').off();
```

Then I'd redo the click handler in this way (I prefer to use the 'on' syntax, since it pairs well with 'off'):

```
$('.show').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('h3').next('.slidetoggle').slideToggle();
});
```

You could shove both in a function like so:

```
function relinkEvents() {
    $('.show').off();
    $('.show').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('h3').next('.slidetoggle').slideToggle();
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @phil function relinkEvents() { $('button.show').off(): $('button.show').on('click', function() { ... }); }

Comment: Not sure what your on click function is, but you can remove from whatever you added it to using the 'off()' function on that same selector.  Then, relink it just as you do in the initial load of the page.  I'd stuff the unlink/relink in a function as I showed above, so you can call it more easily.

Comment: @phil, I added some actual code to my initial answer above.  Try it out and let me know if that works for you.